# Vue JS import global SCSS styles if there is already SASS style

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

As you can see in config file I'm importing global SCSS file, but when I run `npm run serve` it fails because I'm using Vuetify and it is using SASS. Is there way to do it? Or do I have to import SCSS every time I make new component ? Like in old times?

I tried:

```
data: `@import "@/styles/global.scss"
       @import "@/styles/_variables.scss"`
```

also

```
data: `@import "@/styles/global.scss"`
```

`vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: 'sk',
      fallbackLocale: 'sk',
      localeDir: 'locales',
      enableInSFC: false
    }
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "@/styles/global.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should use [style-resources-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-resources-loader).

> This loader is a CSS processor resources loader for `webpack`, which
>   injects your style resources (e.g. `variables` / `mixins`) into multiple
>   imported `css` / `sass` / `scss` / `less` / `stylus` modules.

Vue CLI [Automatic imports](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#automatic-imports).

You can also use the [vue-cli-plugin-style-resources-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-style-resources-loader).

```
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    'style-resources-loader': {
      'patterns': [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles/_variables.scss'),
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i tryed this and now i getting error in every component where i m using something from _variables.scss file   ```Undefined variable.```

Comment: And, please, provide your current config.

Comment: error : ```   Undefined variable. color: $main-color; ```

current config
```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: 'sk',
      fallbackLocale: 'sk',
      localeDir: 'locales',
      enableInSFC: false
    },
    'style-resources-loader': {
      'patterns': [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles/_variables.scss'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles/global.scss'),
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: So, maybe, you don't have `$main-color` defined. It would be nice if you can provide file in which error occurs, along with `_variables.scss` and `global.scss`.

Comment: ```global.scss``` have just global styles for whole app 

in ```_variables.scss``` there is just this

```$bg-color: #15151B;
$main-color: #42b983;```

Comment: Hmm... do you have `@import "_variables.scss";` in `global.scss`?

Comment: nop because i have imported both files with ```style-resources-loader```

Comment: what about ``` path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles/global.scss'),```  if i change here something it doesnt throw error maybe this part is totaly wrong

Comment: Probably, you want to import `_variables.scss` multiple times in different components, but `global.scss` only once, so remove it from here and import it only once in `main.js`. Also don't forget to import `_variables.scss` into `global.scss`.

Comment: importing in main JS was first think i tryed but it will does not fix problem so it looks like i have to import in every component my style ... because i cant figure out what is wrong :/